# Selenium ignores browser version

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-firefoxdriver

I setup a selenium grid and added a chrome, an ie and two firefox (esr and current). It seems to me that setup and the calling code is correct, but the grid/node ignores my browser version for firefox.

I setup two browsers in one node:

```
-browser browserName=firefox,version=34,maxInstances=5,firefox_binary=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe,firefox_profile=standard
-browser browserName=firefox,version=31,maxInstances=5,firefox_binary=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox ESR\firefox.exe,firefox_profile=esr
```

They show up as version 31 and 34 in the grid.

The node logs says they were added:

```
10:09:21.107 INFO [1] org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest - Adding browserName=firefox,version=34,maxInstances=5,firefox_binary=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe,firefox_profile=standard
10:09:21.109 INFO [1] org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest - Adding browserName=firefox,version=31,maxInstances=5,firefox_binary=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox ESR\firefox.exe,firefox_profile=esr
```

When calling the grid with version 31 and 34 both requests are referred to the version 34 instance.

From the Grid log:

```
10:10:38.865 INFO [13] org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{browserName=firefox, version=31, platform=VISTA}]
10:10:38.866 INFO [10] org.openqa.grid.internal.ProxySet - Available nodes: [host :http://sel-node:5555]
10:10:38.866 INFO [10] org.openqa.grid.internal.BaseRemoteProxy - Trying to create a new session on node host :http://sel-node:5555
10:10:38.866 INFO [10] org.openqa.grid.internal.TestSlot - Trying to create a new session on test slot {firefox_binary=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=5, version=34, platform=VISTA, firefox_profile=standard}
10:10:39.388 INFO [35] org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{browserName=firefox, version=34, platform=VISTA}]
10:10:39.388 INFO [10] org.openqa.grid.internal.ProxySet - Available nodes: [host :http://sel-node:5555]
10:10:39.388 INFO [10] org.openqa.grid.internal.BaseRemoteProxy - Trying to create a new session on node host :http://sel-node:5555
10:10:39.388 INFO [10] org.openqa.grid.internal.TestSlot - Trying to create a new session on test slot {firefox_binary=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=5, version=34, platform=VISTA, firefox_profile=standard}
10:26:37.194 INFO [35] org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{browserName=firefox, version=31, platform=VISTA}]
```

The calling code is:

```
URL grid = new URL("http://sel-grid:4444/wd/hub");
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
caps.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA);
caps.setVersion("31"); // or 34
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(grid,caps);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

I left out the chrome and ie configuration. If I call them, they are just triggered fine, but I don't have a version there.

Comment: Did you try like this ?  caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "31");

Comment: Checked that, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. :(

Comment: Do you happen to have Firefox version 34 in your path?

Comment: No. Trying from the commandline it doesn't start firefox.